# How to make use of event bubling in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In Jquery added single event listener to `<ul>`, so that i can listen events on current li using via event bubbling.

```
<ul>
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
 <li>c</li>
 <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest how to achieve the same in angular.
I am trying below way:

1) I can get only selected list element via $event.target, but i unable to get the data bound to list

```
<ul (click)="onListClick($event)">
    <li *ngFor="let data of [1, 2, 3, 4]"></li>
</ul>
```

2) I can get data bound to list in the click listener as i am directly click event on li

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="onListClick(data)" *ngFor="let data of [1, 2, 3, 4]"></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:**
My objective is reduce event listener, so i am binding the event to `<ul>` tag instead of `<li>`, but i have to find the way to get `<li>` data to `<ul>` click listener.

Comment: U could try doing something like this: ```[attr.data-target]="data"``` My question is did u try ```$event.target.value``` ? Set the data to the element and try to extract it by the same attribute.

Comment: Ideally you should first have `data` in your component which is then bound to your `ul`.

Comment: *My objective is reduce event listener*..why? This just seems pointless? The correct thing to do here is to have the click on the `<li>` because that's what your clicking on. There is no advantage that I can see to having the click on the `<ul>`?

Comment: @Liam If we have 100 list item then I have 100 click event listeners, which will cause performance issue, so I thought of having 1 click listener to <ul> instead of 100 click listener at <li>, please correct us if I am wrong

Comment: An event listener is a tiny overhead. Unless you have proof that this is a performance bottle neck then this is premature optimisation ([the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)). I'd say your bigger isssue is who wants to look at 100 li's on a screen!

Answer (score 0):

You can use property binding syntax to set value to list items

```
<ul (click)="onListClick($event)">
    <li *ngFor="let data of [1, 2, 3, 4]" [value]="data">{{data}}</li>
</ul>

onListClick(event) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: as per your suggestion for primitive value it is working fine, but not working when the data is object. please find the stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bubbling-angular?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I assume you can use index ```li *ngFor="let data of employees; let i = index" [attr.data-value]="data" [value]="i">{{data.name}}</li>```